# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_swap", referenced from: _main in swap-315897.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c, compiler-errors, linker-errors

I'm trying to reproduce the code of the book [Effective C: An Introduction to Professional C Programming](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1718501048) by R. Seacord

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap(int, int); // defined in Listing 2-2

int main(void) {
  int a = 21;
  int b = 17;

  swap(a, b);
  printf("main: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile the code on my MacOS 10.15.7 with `gcc swap.c`, I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_swap", referenced from:
      _main in swap-315897.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

What shall I do to correct it?

Comment: `// defined in Listing 2-2`. You need to actually include the definition of `swap` in your code. Find it in the "Listing 2-2" as indicated by comment and enter it into your code.

Comment: BTW, I hope that example is intending to show that the `swap` function does nothing. It definetely does not swap the value of the original input variables.

Comment: @kaylum it must be, [Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/562377/revisions) added that book to the definite book listing last month, so it cannot be complete rubbish  :D